# Fragments with setHasOptionsMenu in ViewPager get onCreateOptionsMenu called multiple times

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-menu

So I have a container for fragments called "container" which is a FrameLayout.

In this container I place a fragment with a ViewPager called CollectionsFragment.

CollectionsFragment has 3 fragments:

- AllCollectionsFragment - setHasOptionsMenu(true)
- MyCollectionsFragment - no menu
- FavouriteCollectionsFragment - no menu

AllCollectionsFragment has a list of collections in it and a spinner menu in the action bar and when the user clicks on a collection another fragment called ViewCollectionFragment is placed in the activity container so:

AllCollectionsFragment -> onClick(position) -> ViewCollectionFragment (placed in main activity container)

The problem is that ViewCollectionFragment does not have menu. It has setHasOptionsMenu(false). But Android still calls AllCollectionsFragment onCreateOptionsMenu even when ViewCollectionFragment is displayed and the menu of AllCollectionsFragment is still displaying when ViewCollectionFragment is visible.

I am using a FragmentStatePagerAdapter and I am passing getChildFragmentManager() of CollectionsFragment to the adapter.

I also have a onBackstackChangeListener for the activity container which invalidates options menu whenever the backstack changes so:
CollectionsFragment -> AllCollectionsFragment (default) -> Select collection -> Add ViewCollectionsFragment in backstack and in main container-> invalidateOptionsMenu -> AllCollectionsFragment.onCreateOptionsMenu is still called and menu is displayed

Any ideas why or I should give more explanation?

Comment: Children of activities/fragments will always combine their options menu with their parent's option menu. Check to see if your MainActivity has an options menu.

Comment: Yes, it has options menu. I want to mention also that I have onBackStackChangeListener for the main container and whenever the backstack is updated an supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered.
That means that when a user is in AllCollectionsFragment -> Press a collection -> Backstack change + invalidate -> ViewCollectionsFragment -> AllCollectionsFragment.onCreateOptionsMenu -> AllCollectionsFragment menu is still visible in ViewCollectionsFragment.
So you mean that this is normal because of the child-parent realtionship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a workaround for this "problem". I am hiding the menu in my main activity (I check if the fragment is there by its tag) and I check in the fragment if the backstack is > 0 and hide the menu...